# How to forkserver for Pytorch multiprocess on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pytorch, multiprocessing, fork

I am in the process of converting code that was written for a Linux machine into code runnable on Windows. The code uses the Pytorch library and the following line called at the very beginning of the script is causing an error:

```
    tr.multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver', force=True)
```

When I change it to `tr.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)`
it works. I read this is because Windows does not have the ability to fork a process. My understanding is that spawn will create a new process without copying any of the data from the parent process. This leaves me with the following two questions:

- What exactly does `tr.multiprocessing.set_start_method()` do? I understand it controls how new processes are started, but when are these new processes started?
- How will spawning instead of forking affect my code? I get this is a broad question, but maybe understanding the first question will help me understand the consequences of spawning.

Comment: On windows, the only available start method is spawn, so attempting to change it will do nothing. On *nix systems, [fork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) copies the memory space (via copy-on-write which can have a perf benefit in some cases) to have access to the target function, and spawn (on all systems) re-runs your code in a fresh interpreter to have access to the target function. This is why code must be import-safe to be multiprocess-safe on a spawn system. **TLDR;** Windows does not have fork. spawn is the only option.